# Как добавить собственное расширение в шаблон PHPixie?

Tags: php, phpixie

> Внимание! Этот вопрос является переводом вопроса: [How to add custom
>   extension for template in
>   PHPixie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46051236/how-to-add-custom-extension-for-template-in-phpixie)

Хочу написать собственное расширение для PHPixie чтобы использовать в шаблоне следующим способом:

```
<div class="title"><?=$formatStyle($person->id, $format_id)?></div>
```

Создал класс расширения как указано в [документации](https://github.com/PHPixie/Template):

```
<?php

namespace Project\App\Template\Extensions\Extension;

class TYM implements \PHPixie\Template\Extensions\Extension
{
    public function name()
    {
        return 'tym';
    }

    public function aliases()
    {
        return array();
    }    

    public function methods()
    {
        return array(
            'formatStyle' => 'format'
        );
    }

    public function format($string, $formtat_id)
    {
        return 'asdf'; // TO DO
    }
}
```

Однако затрудняюсь с тем, куда его положить. Пока создал как класс     `\bundles\app\src\Template\Extensions\Extension\TYM.php` - однако расширение не подключается.

Как это исправить?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46051236/how-to-add-custom-extension-for-template-in-phpixie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подключение расширений осуществляется в классе `Project/Framework/Extensions.php`. Просто отредактируйте метод `templateExtensions()` следующим образом:

```
/**
 * Extensions for the Template component
 * @return array
 */
public function templateExtensions()
{
    return array_merge(parent::templateExtensions(), array(
        //add your Template Extensions here
        new \Project\App\Template\Extensions\Extension\Base64()
    ));
}
```

Для вашего случая (класс `\bundles\app\src\Template\Extensions\Extension\TYM.php`) это будет:

```
return array_merge(parent::templateExtensions(), array(
    //add your Template Extensions here
    new \Project\App\Template\Extensions\Extension\TYM()
));
```